# Pandas: MID & FIND Function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the a column in my dataframe that shows different combinations of the values below.  I know that I could use the .str[:3] function and then convert this to a value, but the differing string lengths are throwing me off. How would I do a MID(x,FIND(",",x,1)+1,10) esk function on this column to find the sentiment and subjectivity values?

String samples:

```
df['Output'] = 

Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)
Sentiment(polarity=-0.03958333333333333, subjectivity=0.5020833333333334)
Sentiment(polarity=0.16472802559759075, subjectivity=0.4024750611707134)
```

Error:

```
def senti(x):
    return TextBlob(x).sentiment

df['Output'] = df['stop'].apply(senti)
df.Output.str.split(',|=',expand=True).iloc[:,[1,3]]

IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds
```

Outputs:

```
0                                       (0.0, 0.0)
1     (0.0028273809523809493, 0.48586309523809534)
2          (0.153726035868893, 0.5354359925788496)
3        (0.04357142857142857, 0.5319047619047619)
4       (0.07575757575757575, 0.28446969696969693)
                          ...                     
92                    (0.225, 0.39642857142857146)
93                                      (0.0, 0.0)
94        (0.5428571428571429, 0.6428571428571428)
95      (0.14393939393939395, 0.39999999999999997)
96       (0.35833333333333334, 0.5777777777777778)
Name: Output, Length: 97, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[['polarity', 'subjectivity']] = df.Output.str.split(',|=|\)',expand=True).iloc[:,[1,3]]
```

Result:

```
                                              Output              polarity        subjectivity
0          Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)                   0.0                 0.0
1  Sentiment(polarity=-0.03958333333333333, subje...  -0.03958333333333333  0.5020833333333334
2  Sentiment(polarity=0.16472802559759075, subjec...   0.16472802559759075  0.4024750611707134
```

Comment: Thanks! I am receiving an error when running this code though... I uploaded my lines as well as the error that I'm receiving

Comment: that means that (in some rows) there are less than 4 columns after splitting. You should check the data in the Output column and maybe adopt the regex accordingly.

Comment: Still receiving an error here... I screenshotted my actual code. Thoughts?

Comment: you should look at your df.Output data, can you show them?

Comment: Just posted what the output data looks like

Comment: It will fail always whenever pattern of these 2 variables is different, order is different, or the result is `None`... Works only for perfect cases...

Comment: All rows shown in your screenshot should work, other patterns (different order or None results etc.) won't work (nor would your Excel formula work in these cases). Extracting the values as per @GrzegorzSkibinski's answer should work better here.

Comment: All of the records look the exact same on my side, just differing numbers of course. No blanks or anything.... Is the issue related to the negative signs?

Comment: No, minus signs have no effect. The regex just splits the string at all comma, equal signs or closing parenthesis and then takes the second and fourth columns (i.e. #1 and #3). If any of these three characters show up at different places in the string it will fail.

Comment: Weirdly enough, when I try the find function it shows NaN everywhere, which led me to print df['Output'] within Sublime. As you can see above, the results in Sublime are simply (###,####) while the Excel outputs are Sentiment(polarity=###,subj.=####). Any idea why?

Comment: Even weirder, I added a new column df['test'] = df['Output'].str[:3] and it returned the entire (0.0028273809523809493, 0.48586309523809534) result per row

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df['polarity']=df['Output'].str.extract(r"polarity=([-\.\d]+)")
df['subjectivity']=df['Output'].str.extract(r"subjectivity=([-\.\d]+)")
```

Outputs:

```py
>>> df.iloc[:, -2:]
               polarity        subjectivity
0  0.0                   0.0
1  -0.03958333333333333  0.5020833333333334
2  0.16472802559759075   0.4024750611707134
```

Comment: thanks for the response. This yields blank results for some reason... Any idea why?

Comment: Hm that's odd - can you share the exact code you tried?

Comment: Added the code screenshots and the Output column results

Comment: Added a screenshot with yours.... As I mentioned, this one works but it returns just blank values

Comment: Hm, still odd - can you try: `df['polarity']=df['Output'].str.extract(r"polarity=([-\.\d]+)")` also can you share again `Output`, you don't have spaces in there around equality sign `=`?

Comment: Weirdly enough, when I try the find function it shows NaN everywhere, which led me to print df['Output'] within Sublime. As you can see above, the results in Sublime are simply (###,####) while the Excel outputs are Sentiment(polarity=###,subj.=####). Any idea why?

Comment: Again, that's not the code I supplied you with - try: `df['subjectivity']=df['Output'].str.extract(r"subjectivity=([-\.\d]+)")` (analogically for other measures).